# ng-click is not working with AngularJS and jquery dataTables if using row.add

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am new to angualrjs , I am using jQuery DataTable directive with angularJS which is working fine. The problem I am facing is adding javascript function to "TR" dynamically with "ng-click" which is not working. It seem's like dynamically added elements are not recognized by angular.

Can somebody help me out solving this problem.

There are many questions in Stackoverflow and mentioned solution I already tried but not working actually I am using row.add method of jquery for popluating rows.

Please find the code which I am using

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$filter','$http', '$compile', function($scope, $filter, $http,$compile) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() {        
            $http.get('http://localhost:9999/Angular_web/rest/main_search/byaufnum/').
            then(function(response) {
                var mytable = $('#table1').DataTable();
                response.data.map(function(item) {
                    mytable.row.add(['<span style=\'white-space: nowrap\'><a href=javascript:angular.noop(); ng-click=\"getBGPdata(\''+item.auftragsNr+'\')\">'+item.auftragsNr+'</a></span>']);
                    $compile(mytable.row)($scope);
                })
                mytable.draw(false);
            }); 
    };

    $scope.getBGPdata = function(searchValue) {
        console.log('--> '+searchValue);
    };
}]);
```

I know that that problem can be resolved by using `$compile and $scope` but not sure how to add this in above code.

[image]

Below is the HTML of redering table

```
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1"><span style="white-space: nowrap"><a href="javascript:angular.noop();" ng-click="getBGPdata('KRT-ZDK-PMN_NEU-WWT_loopback_SFV_1')">KRT-ZDK-PMN_NEU-WWT_loopback_SFV_1</a></span></td>
```

Comment: move this `$compile(mytable)($scope);` to after `mytable.draw(false);`

Comment: @Jag still its not working .

Comment: did you able to see rendered DataTable without any errors? any console errors?

Comment: Yeah I am able to see the table without any error, I have also attached the screen shot.

Comment: @prashantthakre can you show us the HTML of rendered table row ?

Comment: @GangadharJannu yeah i also added the HTML code as well in post.

Comment: @GangadharJannu If row.add is causing this issue then I am also ready to change the code as per suggestion

Comment: @ check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42401345/3543808)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

issue is compiling `mytable` which is not a DOM element (its a DataTable instance object)

so you need to do it like this

```
      var table = $('#table1');
      var mytable = table.DataTable();
      response.data.forEach(function(item) {
        mytable.row.add(['<span style=\'white-space: nowrap\'><a href=javascript:angular.noop(); ng-click=\"getBGPdata(\'' + item.auftragsNr + '\')\">' + item.auftragsNr + '</a></span>']);
      })
      mytable.draw(false);
      $compile(table)($scope); // here table not mytable
```

working example [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bff17185/)

**EDIT**

DataTables will only render first page initially, so when you apply `$compile(table)($scope);` its only compiling first page rows, not all rows (since they are not yet rendered).

to fix this issue, you need to compile all rows before adding them to DataTable

```
    success: function(data) {
      var mytable = table.DataTable();
      var tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>');
      data.forEach(function(item) {
        tbody.append('<tr><td><span style="white-space: nowrap"><a href="javascript:angular.noop();" ng-click="getBGPdata(\'' + item.auftragsNr + '\')">' + item.auftragsNr + '</a></span></td></tr>');
      })
      // compiling all rows under tbody
      $compile(tbody[0])($scope)
      // adding only trs from tbody to DataTable
      mytable.rows.add(tbody[0].children).draw(false);
    }
```

also here is an updated [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bff17185/1/) with paging

Comment: Excellent, I struggled a lot but this one didn't trigger to me, Thanks a lot now its working perfeclty.

Comment: Links are working fine in first page but when I going to next page again links stopped working. I am showing 10 links per page so first page links are working when I am clicking on next page then in next page's record links are not working.

Answer (score 1):

> It is not advisable to do service calls and `DOM` manipulation in controllers.
>   For that you can use `factory/service/proider` and `directive` respectively.

I guess the issue is with mytable.row which is not at all holding the row instances that you've added.
It should `mytable.row(index)`.

So Instead of compiling `mytable.row` add all the rows and compile the table once with `$compile(angular.element('#table1'))($scope);`.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$filter','$http', '$compile', function($scope, $filter, $http,$compile) {
    $scope.myFunc = function() {        
            $http.get('http://localhost:9999/Angular_web/rest/main_search/byaufnum/').
            then(function(response) {
                var mytable = $('#table1').DataTable();
                response.data.map(function(item) {
                    mytable.row.add(['<span style=\'white-space: nowrap\'><a href=javascript:angular.noop(); ng-click=\"getBGPdata(\''+item.auftragsNr+'\')\">'+item.auftragsNr+'</a></span>']);
                });
                mytable.draw(false);
                $compile(angular.element('#table1'))($scope);
            }); 
    };

    $scope.getBGPdata = function(searchValue) {
        console.log('--> '+searchValue);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: No this is not working , I also tried this option but no at all working.

Comment: @prashantthakre can you check with `$compile(angular.element('#table1'))($scope);` as updated in the answer

Comment: No its not working, However answered by Jag is working fine for me, Thanks for your effort, I was doing mistake I had to use `$compile($('#table1'))($scope);`

Comment: @prashantthakre Did you checked the modified code I've suggested. Selecting an element with $ or angular.element is similar. And the mistake you are saying I've already suggested